# Add google map in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, google-maps

I'm new in wordpress. I want to add a map in my wordpress site. Which plugin is better for it?
The plugin should be easier to use as I'm new.

Thanks in advance

Comment: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The plugin I prefer for wordpress google map is http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wp-google-maps/

It easy to use & can be used in post or page & widgets.

Here you'll find a tutorial on using it http://www.shartd.com/wordpress/advanced-wordpress-tutorial/how-to-add-google-map-in-wordpress/

Answer (score 0):

You don't really need a plugin for this. Installing lots of plugins will make your wordpress install slow.

You can insert the google map script straight into your page or post content, or even your theme template.

Answer (score 0):

If it's just a single post you want it on then don't bother with a plugin, it will needlessly slow down your site. Just get the embed code from Google Maps.

If you want to tag multiple posts the try [GeoMashup](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/geo-mashup/)